# Asynchronous function to get files from directory not working as expected

Tags: c#, file, asynchronous

I'm working on a Blazor project.
I try to make a asynchronous function to get ".avi" and ".mkv" files from directory. But When I try to access the page instead of having my "Loading..." message, it takes times until I got all the result in one time.

Here is the code of my service:

```
namespace FilesScanner
{
    public class FilesScannerService
    {
        public async Task<IEnumerable<FileInfo>> GetFilesAsync(string path,
            EnumerationOptions options, string[] extensions)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new(path);

            return await Task.Run(() => extensions.SelectMany(x => dir.EnumerateFiles(x, options)
                .Where(f => !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))));
        }
    }
}
```

There is the code of the Blazor page where I call the above function:

```
using FilesScanner;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace MovieLibrary.Pages
{
    public partial class Files
    {
        [Inject] private FilesScannerService _scannerService { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<FileInfo> FilesInfos { get; set; }

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\username\Videos";

            string[] extensions =
            {
                "*.avi",
                "*.mkv"
            };

            EnumerationOptions opts = new()
            {
                IgnoreInaccessible = true,
                RecurseSubdirectories = true
            };

            FilesInfos = await _scannerService.GetFilesAsync(path, opts ,extensions);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the code where I display the result:

```
@page "/files"
@using System.IO;
<h3>Movies</h3>

@if (FilesInfos is not null)
{
    try
    {
        int i = 1;
        foreach (FileInfo file in FilesInfos)
        {
            <p><span style="font-weight:700">@i :</span> @Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@file.Name)</p>
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        <p>@ex.Message</p>
    }
}
else
{
    <h2>LOADING...</h2>
}
```

Did I misunderstood something with asynchronous function?

Comment: Don't mix async and IEnumerable. Just return the IEnumerable and it should defer execution automatically, i.e. get one file, render it, then get the next file etc.

Comment: Also, your UI lists an arbitrary (_possibly very large_) number of entries. Does that _really_ make sense? As a User, I won't scroll down to Item No. 123456764323456 But I'll happily jump to page 20 or to "Start with 'W'" ...

Comment: You followed that description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#handle-incomplete-async-actions-at-render)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetFilesAsync` returns an `Task<IEnumerable<FileInfo>>`. Assuming that your intention is to do all the work asyncronously, that's a problem. The bulk of the work is not done before completing the [`Task<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1), but as part of enumerating the [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1). If you want to offload all the work to the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool), make sure to change the return type of the method to `Task<FileInfo[]>` (a `Task` that returns an array of `FileInfo`). The arrays (and lists) are materialized. The enumerable sequences usually aren't, because they can be implemented with [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/deferred-execution-lazy-evaluation#deferred-execution).

Comment: Thanks, Indeed the IEnumerable was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way might be to *not* `await` for the result. Because you actually do not to wait for it before rendering!

Instead, start the process and render your loading, then after finishing, update the UI (maybe call `StateHasChanged()` as needed).

Something like this:

```cs
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    // Start the file fetching operation without awaiting it
    _ = LoadFilesAsync();
}

private async Task LoadFilesAsync()
{
    FilesInfos = await _scannerService.GetFilesAsync(path, opts, extensions);

    StateHasChanged(); // Force UI to update, not sure if required (probably)
}
```